# Long table environment not working properly

Tags: longtable

I'm writing a long table but the contents of the long table are separately written. How can I embed it properly to work. Please run the code to see the self-explaining problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\testfileexists}[1]{%
    \IfFileExists{#1}%
    {\def\inputtestedfile{\@@input #1 }}
    {\let\inputtestedfile\@empty}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{TR2.1}
\begin{small}\begin{tabular}{|l|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|}
        \hline
        &\textbf{Min. [mm]}&\textbf{Max. [mm]}&\textbf{Mean [mm]}&\textbf{deviation [mm]}\\\hline
        \textbf{01.07.2014}&-0.134&-0.051&-0.104&0.019\\\hline
        \textbf{08.07.2014}&-0.147&-0.101&-0.136&0.010\\\hline
        \textbf{15.07.2014}&-0.172&-0.101&-0.142&0.018\\\hline
        \textbf{22.07.2014}&-0.182&-0.142&-0.169&0.010\\\hline
        \textbf{29.07.2014}&-0.191&-0.156&-0.180&0.009\\\hline
        \textbf{05.08.2014}&-0.196&-0.161&-0.183&0.008\\\hline
        \textbf{12.08.2014}&-0.189&-0.171&-0.183&0.004\\\hline
        \textbf{19.08.2014}&-0.188&-0.165&-0.180&0.005\\\hline
        \textbf{26.08.2014}&-0.186&-0.148&-0.177&0.008\\\hline
        \textbf{02.09.2014}&-0.189&-0.161&-0.179&0.006\\\hline
        \textbf{09.09.2014}&-0.186&-0.170&-0.180&0.003\\\hline
        \textbf{16.09.2014}&-0.188&-0.172&-0.182&0.004\\\hline
        \textbf{23.09.2014}&-0.187&-0.172&-0.179&0.003\\\hline
        \textbf{30.09.2014}&-0.185&-0.175&-0.181&0.002\\\hline
        \textbf{07.10.2014}&-0.184&-0.175&-0.179&0.002\\\hline
        \textbf{14.10.2014}&-0.182&-0.173&-0.179&0.002\\\hline
        \textbf{21.10.2014}&-0.184&-0.175&-0.179&0.002\\\hline
        \textbf{28.10.2014}&-0.183&-0.173&-0.178&0.002\\\hline
        \textbf{04.11.2014}&-0.182&-0.174&-0.179&0.002\\\hline
        \textbf{11.11.2014}&-0.178&-0.174&-0.176&0.001\\\hline
        \textbf{18.11.2014}&-0.178&-0.173&-0.176&0.001\\\hline
        \textbf{25.11.2014}&-0.180&-0.176&-0.177&0.001\\\hline
        \textbf{02.12.2014}&-0.177&-0.172&-0.175&0.002\\\hline
        \textbf{09.12.2014}&-0.179&-0.174&-0.176&0.001\\\hline
        \textbf{16.12.2014}&-0.180&-0.173&-0.176&0.002\\\hline
        \textbf{23.12.2014}&-0.183&-0.177&-0.180&0.002\\\hline
        \textbf{30.12.2014}&-0.178&-0.175&-0.177&0.001\\\hline
        \textbf{06.01.2015}&-0.182&-0.173&-0.177&0.002\\\hline
        \textbf{13.01.2015}&-0.181&-0.175&-0.178&0.002\\\hline
        \textbf{20.01.2015}&-0.179&-0.173&-0.175&0.002\\\hline
        \textbf{27.01.2015}&-0.176&-0.172&-0.175&0.001\\\hline
        \textbf{03.02.2015}&-0.177&-0.172&-0.174&0.001\\\hline
        \textbf{10.02.2015}&-0.178&-0.170&-0.175&0.002\\\hline
        \textbf{17.02.2015}&-0.176&-0.168&-0.174&0.002\\\hline
        \textbf{24.02.2015}&-0.178&-0.170&-0.174&0.002\\\hline
        \textbf{03.03.2015}&-0.177&-0.162&-0.173&0.003\\\hline
        \textbf{10.03.2015}&-0.181&-0.169&-0.176&0.003\\\hline
        \textbf{17.03.2015}&-0.179&-0.163&-0.174&0.004\\\hline
        \textbf{24.03.2015}&-0.178&-0.158&-0.174&0.004\\\hline
        \textbf{31.03.2015}&-0.178&-0.152&-0.172&0.006\\\hline
        \textbf{07.04.2015}&-0.183&-0.138&-0.171&0.010\\\hline
        \textbf{14.04.2015}&-0.183&-0.139&-0.171&0.012\\\hline
        \textbf{21.04.2015}&-0.182&-0.143&-0.172&0.009\\\hline
        \textbf{28.04.2015}&-0.184&-0.144&-0.170&0.009\\\hline
        \textbf{05.05.2015}&-0.185&-0.146&-0.176&0.008\\\hline
        \textbf{12.05.2015}&-0.186&-0.155&-0.176&0.008\\\hline
        \textbf{19.05.2015}&-0.183&-0.146&-0.172&0.008\\\hline
        \textbf{26.05.2015}&-0.183&-0.154&-0.174&0.007\\\hline
        \textbf{02.06.2015}&-0.190&-0.102&-0.172&0.016\\\hline
        \textbf{09.06.2015}&-0.191&-0.132&-0.175&0.015\\\hline
        \textbf{16.06.2015}&-0.186&-0.154&-0.179&0.007\\\hline
        \textbf{23.06.2015}&-0.187&-0.132&-0.173&0.013\\\hline
        \textbf{30.06.2015}&-0.201&-0.126&-0.175&0.019\\\hline
        \textbf{07.07.2015}&-0.196&-0.151&-0.185&0.010\\\hline
        \textbf{14.07.2015}&-0.193&-0.140&-0.180&0.012\\\hline
        \textbf{21.07.2015}&-0.193&-0.162&-0.182&0.007\\\hline
        \textbf{28.07.2015}&-0.186&-0.104&-0.170&0.021\\\hline
        \textbf{04.08.2015}&-0.191&-0.122&-0.172&0.016\\\hline
        \textbf{11.08.2015}&-0.189&-0.156&-0.181&0.008\\\hline
        \textbf{18.08.2015}&-0.191&-0.147&-0.178&0.011\\\hline
        \textbf{25.08.2015}&-0.188&-0.137&-0.175&0.012\\\hline
        \textbf{01.09.2015}&-0.192&-0.153&-0.182&0.009\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{small}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
\caption{A simple longtable example}\\
\hline
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\hline
\endlastfoot
R1&\input{TR2.1}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to nest a `tabular` enviroment, which cannot be broken across pages, inside a `longtable` environment?

Comment: Where should the "R1" be situated? If the inner table gets longer this is not clear. You do not need the `center` here, as `longtable`centres by default.

Comment: R1 should be in right middle of the TR.1. I don't want but if I skip R1, is there any  solution of my problem.

Comment: It is not at all clear what your problem is (or what this code is intended to do)  you have a longtable in a center environment (which does nothing useful) and then you are including a large normal non-breaking tabular into a single cell in the second column of the longtable so that clearly will not break over a page

Answer (score 1):

The rules for setting `R1` are pretty unclear to me, are there `R2`, `R3`? What about the second page. Maybe it can be added to the header or caption of the table. Or it can be added as separate line above the data rows.

A version of the table without `R1`, but more nicely formatted IMHO.

Anyway, the data lines should be at top level. TeX can only break a top-level table between rows. A table cell, even if it contains another table is an unbreakable object.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \small
  \newcommand*{\headmm}{\textbf{[mm]}}
  \begin{longtable}{
    >{\bfseries}l
    *{3}{S[table-format=-1.3]}
    S[table-format=1.3]
  }
    \caption{A simple longtable example}\\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Date} & {\bfseries Min.} & {\bfseries Max.} &
    {\bfseries Mean} & {\bfseries Deviation} \\
    & {\headmm} & {\headmm} & {\headmm} & {\headmm} \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{%
      \tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}%
    } \\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Date} & {\bfseries Min.} & {\bfseries Max.} &
    {\bfseries Mean} & {\bfseries Deviation} \\
    & {\headmm} & {\headmm} & {\headmm} & {\headmm} \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    01.07.2014&-0.134&-0.051&-0.104&0.019\\
    08.07.2014&-0.147&-0.101&-0.136&0.010\\
    15.07.2014&-0.172&-0.101&-0.142&0.018\\
    22.07.2014&-0.182&-0.142&-0.169&0.010\\
    29.07.2014&-0.191&-0.156&-0.180&0.009\\
    05.08.2014&-0.196&-0.161&-0.183&0.008\\
    12.08.2014&-0.189&-0.171&-0.183&0.004\\
    19.08.2014&-0.188&-0.165&-0.180&0.005\\
    26.08.2014&-0.186&-0.148&-0.177&0.008\\
    02.09.2014&-0.189&-0.161&-0.179&0.006\\
    09.09.2014&-0.186&-0.170&-0.180&0.003\\
    16.09.2014&-0.188&-0.172&-0.182&0.004\\
    23.09.2014&-0.187&-0.172&-0.179&0.003\\
    30.09.2014&-0.185&-0.175&-0.181&0.002\\
    07.10.2014&-0.184&-0.175&-0.179&0.002\\
    14.10.2014&-0.182&-0.173&-0.179&0.002\\
    21.10.2014&-0.184&-0.175&-0.179&0.002\\
    28.10.2014&-0.183&-0.173&-0.178&0.002\\
    04.11.2014&-0.182&-0.174&-0.179&0.002\\
    11.11.2014&-0.178&-0.174&-0.176&0.001\\
    18.11.2014&-0.178&-0.173&-0.176&0.001\\
    25.11.2014&-0.180&-0.176&-0.177&0.001\\
    02.12.2014&-0.177&-0.172&-0.175&0.002\\
    09.12.2014&-0.179&-0.174&-0.176&0.001\\
    16.12.2014&-0.180&-0.173&-0.176&0.002\\
    23.12.2014&-0.183&-0.177&-0.180&0.002\\
    30.12.2014&-0.178&-0.175&-0.177&0.001\\
    06.01.2015&-0.182&-0.173&-0.177&0.002\\
    13.01.2015&-0.181&-0.175&-0.178&0.002\\
    20.01.2015&-0.179&-0.173&-0.175&0.002\\
    27.01.2015&-0.176&-0.172&-0.175&0.001\\
    03.02.2015&-0.177&-0.172&-0.174&0.001\\
    10.02.2015&-0.178&-0.170&-0.175&0.002\\
    17.02.2015&-0.176&-0.168&-0.174&0.002\\
    24.02.2015&-0.178&-0.170&-0.174&0.002\\
    03.03.2015&-0.177&-0.162&-0.173&0.003\\
    10.03.2015&-0.181&-0.169&-0.176&0.003\\
    17.03.2015&-0.179&-0.163&-0.174&0.004\\
    24.03.2015&-0.178&-0.158&-0.174&0.004\\
    31.03.2015&-0.178&-0.152&-0.172&0.006\\
    07.04.2015&-0.183&-0.138&-0.171&0.010\\
    14.04.2015&-0.183&-0.139&-0.171&0.012\\
    21.04.2015&-0.182&-0.143&-0.172&0.009\\
    28.04.2015&-0.184&-0.144&-0.170&0.009\\
    05.05.2015&-0.185&-0.146&-0.176&0.008\\
    12.05.2015&-0.186&-0.155&-0.176&0.008\\
    19.05.2015&-0.183&-0.146&-0.172&0.008\\
    26.05.2015&-0.183&-0.154&-0.174&0.007\\
    02.06.2015&-0.190&-0.102&-0.172&0.016\\
    09.06.2015&-0.191&-0.132&-0.175&0.015\\
    16.06.2015&-0.186&-0.154&-0.179&0.007\\
    23.06.2015&-0.187&-0.132&-0.173&0.013\\
    30.06.2015&-0.201&-0.126&-0.175&0.019\\
    07.07.2015&-0.196&-0.151&-0.185&0.010\\
    14.07.2015&-0.193&-0.140&-0.180&0.012\\
    21.07.2015&-0.193&-0.162&-0.182&0.007\\
    28.07.2015&-0.186&-0.104&-0.170&0.021\\
    04.08.2015&-0.191&-0.122&-0.172&0.016\\
    11.08.2015&-0.189&-0.156&-0.181&0.008\\
    18.08.2015&-0.191&-0.147&-0.178&0.011\\
    25.08.2015&-0.188&-0.137&-0.175&0.012\\
    01.09.2015&-0.192&-0.153&-0.182&0.009\\
  \end{longtable}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Page 1:

> [image: Page 1]

Page 2:

> [image: Page 2]

Comment: I getting an error 'Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (S): `c' used. } I 'm getting this table from another function and I have to only input this table (TR2.1.tex). This code is part of a big script.

Comment: @user31177 You need to load package `siunitx` for the example. This package provides column type `S`, which allows to align numbers at the decimal marker in table columns.